# Need to get wordpress files after my vm instance is shutdown due to owing on google cloud

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, ftp

I have 6 google VM instance which have been shut down due to owing, I currently can't pay but need access to some particular files requested by an important client.

I need your help to gain access to the directory in which my WordPress files are installed.

Comment: We cannot help you on Stackoverflow. There are no secrets to getting data from services that are shutdown. Remember, you have apx 30 days to settle the outstanding balance before the data is deleted. You might try working with Google Cloud Billing on your situation. Open a billing support ticket.

Comment: Allright thanks for the feedback, appreciate it. Will do so quickly

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access your files unless you communicate your issue with the Google Cloud Platform through its Support. [Contact the billing support team](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_platform_billing)  through a Support Ticket, Chat, Mail or Phone.

You may also report your issue with [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers). Please make sure to file your ticket under the right component.

Comment: Okay did that, I am yet to get a solution. I appreciate your solution, thanks very much